# Is it possible to get specific column data from a large pipe delimited file without creating a class for every column?

Tags: c#, delimiter

I am writing a C# program that will grab some data from a pipe delimited file with 400 columns in it. I'm only required to work with 6 of the columns in each row. The file does not have headers, and the first line is a 5 column row with general description of file (file name, batch date, number of records, total, report id). Before I create a class with 400 fields in it, I was curious if anyone here had a better idea of how to approach this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: just split the line by tokens (using either string-split or spans) and look at the pieces you want, and ignore all the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't mention much as to how you're loading the file, but I imagine it is using System.IO and then doing a string split on each line.  If so, you need not extract every field in the resulting splitted array.

Imagine you only needed two columns, the second and fourth, and had a class to accept each row as follows:

```
public class row {
    public string field2;
    public string field4;
}
```

Then you would extract your data like this:

```
IEnumerable<row> parsed = 
    File.ReadLines(@"path to file")
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(line => {
        var splitted = line.Split('|');
        return new row { 
            field2 = splitted[1], 
            field4 = splitted[3] 
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO reference and then do something like this:

```
using(var parser = new TextFieldParsser(file))
{
Int32 skipHeader = 0;
parser.SetDelimiters("|");
while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    //Processing row
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    Int32 x = 0;

    if (skipHeader > 0)
    {
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (x == 0)
            {
                //SAVE STUFF TO VARIABLE
            }
            else if (x==4)
            {
                //SAVE MORE STUFF
            }
            else if (x == 20)
            {
                //SAVE LAST STUFF

                break;//THIS IS THE LAST COLUMN OF DATA NEEDED SO YOU BREAK
            }

            x++;
        }
        //DO SOMETHING WITH ALL THE SAVED STUFF AND CLEAR IT OUT
    }
    else
    {
        skipHeader++;
    }
}}
```